# Trasnsate bash script with ip-utility calls to /etc/network/interface

Tags: linux, tunneling

I use the services of a Scaleway provider. I have a public instance and a few private ones. The problem is that private interfaces do not have access to the Internet.

There is an idea to organize NAT through a public instance -
https://community.online.net/t/yet-another-tutorial-to-create-a-private-network/5090
This article describes how to raise GRE tunnels. But everything is tied to the use of bash skyrtta and utilities ip.

```
#!/bin/bash

REMOTE_ADDR="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX92.priv.cloud.scaleway.com
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX93.priv.cloud.scaleway.com"

ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip addr add 172.16.42.254/24 dev br0
ip link set br0 up

for ADDR in $REMOTE_ADDR; do
        IP=$(getent hosts $ADDR | awk '{ print $1 }')
        IP_SANITIZED=$(echo $IP | sed 's/\./-/g')
        TUN_DEV="tun-"$IP_SANITIZED

        ip link add $TUN_DEV type gretap remote $IP ttl 64
        ip link set dev $TUN_DEV up
        ip link set dev $TUN_DEV master br0
done
```

Now I'm trying to convert this to the format of the */etc/network/interfaces* file. But its not working for me.

My experiment:

```
iface br0 inet static
  description create bridge interface
  address 172.16.42.254
  netmask 24

  # hook scripts
  pre-up ip link add name br0 type bridge
  post-up ip link add tun-1 type gretap remote 10.16.167.11 ttl 64
  post-up ip link set dev tun-1 up
  post-up ip link set dev tun-1 master br0
  post-up ip link add tun-2 type gretap remote 10.16.157.141 ttl 64
  post-up ip link set dev tun-2 up
  post-up ip link set dev tun-2 master br0
  post-up ip link add tun-3 type gretap remote 10.16.119.13 ttl 64
  post-up ip link set dev tun-3 up
  post-up ip link set dev tun-3 master br0
```